# ListView - view is related with many rows

Tags: java, android, listview

I want item from ListView disappear when I touch it. It is working but
problem is when I scroll list. Random items are disappearing or showing.
This is my code:

```
private ListView list;
(...)
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.units_list);
adapter = new UnitAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list, units);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    });
```

ListView XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/units_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
</ListView>
```

row_list.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/upgrade"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

I tried too:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            list.getChildAt(position).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

And even:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            list.getChildAt((int) id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

But it works same.
What is the problem? Why View is related with multiple rows? How can I fix this?

Comment: listview reuse the item outside the visible area

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the fact that a view in a ListView is recycled in Android, so when you edit a row you may see the difference when you scroll in multiple rows.

One solution could be to update the underlying adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged. But there may be smoother solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use View Holder design pattern.
2. when you are removing the item from List View, remove the same from list(in your case unit) also.